# Display incoming call notification when flutter app is terminated or in a background

Tags: flutter, sockets, dart

is there a way to display incoming call notifications when the `flutter app` is terminated or in the background? I tried to use `connectyCube` package, but too complex. Also, I used the flutter `background service` to listen to incoming calls with `socket.io` but the app got crashed when it is launched from the background. I need your guidance.

Comment: You can use [flutter_local_notifications package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use native code in android for incoming call notification.

For Android you can use HeadsUpNotificationService as we use in native.

And for Ios you can use https://github.com/peerwaya/flutter_call_kit

Comment: I used this package https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_callkit_incoming for incoming calls and other events it offers. I marked your answer because the package you mentioned has kind of similar features as the one I used. For listening to the incoming calls, I used FCM services to do it.